# Changing opacity of KML overlay in Google maps V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, opacity

Been looking for a solution to what seems like a relatively simple problem. I have a kml layer loaded into google maps. It outputs as a  within the dom and I have been able to identify its location.
What I want to do is simply change the opacity. I have tried using simple css targeting and that doesn't seem to work.
I have also tried to add a class to the function calling the kml layer in javascript (however my knowledge of javascript is rudimentary at best)
None of the answers to the other questions directly apply (or at least I cant see how they would)

here is my code: adding the kml layer and below that the div it outputs to in the dom.

KML add - 
`var geoLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.tijaniogunlende.com/dataviz/doc.kml');
                geoLayer.setMap(map);
                geoLayer.addClass( "overlay" );`

and the DOM output - 
[image]

By the way, it works just fine when I edit the css directly in chrome, but since it's styled inline I cant pinpoint where to insert the css in my code, nor can I target the element properly. At this point I'd prefer a javascript solution.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implemented method that returns a pointer to the DOMNode that contains the elements of the layer.

But in this case, where all the GroundOverlays will be loaded from the same address, you may use a CSS-attribute-selector to apply a custom styling for the images, e.g.:

```
img[src^="http://gisatnrel.nrel.gov/"]{
    opacity:.5;
}
```